# Creating a JavaScript object in a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page using DataTables to display a list of customers (test_viewcustomers.php).  I set my DataTable as "oTable" so I can manipulate it and make it clickable to open a dialog window.

The dialog window (test_customers_edit.php) has another DataTable in it that I defined as "zTable".  zTable loads data via ajax, but I want to update it every few seconds with the fnReloadAjax function in DataTables... the problem is when I try to reference zTable I'm told it's not defined.  In the console I can find oTable just fine, but zTable doesn't exist.  In fact if I try to make any variable inside of the dialog window, it simply doesn't exist.

I feel like I'm simply doing this the wrong way.  Here's some code snippets:

test_viewcustomers.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>View Customers</title>
<link href="css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datatables.fnReloadAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    oTable = $('#tblRecords').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Search:" },
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bSort": false
    });
    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 0, false ); // Hide the Agent ID


    $('#tblRecords tbody').delegate( 'tr', 'click', function() {
        var customerId = oTable.fnGetData( this, 0 );
        var userName = oTable.fnGetData( this, 2 );


        var Url = "test_customers_edit.php?customerid=" + customerId;
        $.ajax({
            url: Url,
            success: function( result ) {
                $('#dialog-customer-container').html( result );
                $( "#dialog-customer-stats" ).dialog( "open" );
                $('#dialog-customer-stats').dialog('option', 'title', 'Customer Detail - '+userName+'');
            }
        }); 
    });
    $('#tblRecords tbody').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
        });


    $('#dialog-customer-stats').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 850,
        modal: true,
        close: function() {
            $('#dialog-customer-stats form input').val('').removeClass( 'ui-state-error' );
        }
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0px" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="0px">
  <tr>
    <td class="topHeading"> Customers </td>
    <td align="right"></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="viewWidth"><table id="tblRecords" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> CustomerID </th>
            <th> Agent </th>
            <th> Business Name </th>
            <th> First Name </th>
            <th> Last Name </th>
            <th> Phone </th>
            <th> Email </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>Agent A Enterprises</td>
        <td>TimCo</td>
        <td>Tim</td>
        <td>Whitaker</td>
        <td>(888) 888-8888</td>
        <td>wirikidor@yahoo.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>Agent A Enterprises</td>
        <td>TimCo</td>
        <td>Tim</td>
        <td>Whitaker</td>
        <td>(888) 888-8888</td>
        <td>wirikidor5@yahoo.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="dialog-customer-stats" title="Customer Info">
  <div id="dialog-customer-container"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

test_customers_edit.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var zTable = $('#tblDIDs').dataTable({
        "sDom": 't',
        "bSort": false,
    "sAjaxSource": 'getDID.json',
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "COS" },
        { "mData": "CODE1" },
        { "mData": "CODE2" },
        { "mData": "FLAG_ACTIVE" },
        { "mData": "LAST_UPDATE_DTTM" }
        ]           
    });
});
</script>

<table border="0px" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="0px">
  <tr>
    <td class="topHeading">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="viewWidth"><table id="tblDIDs" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> COS </th>
            <th> Number </th>
            <th> Rule/Group </th>
            <th> Active </th>
            <th> Last Updated </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

getDID.json

```
 {"aaData":[{"COS":"COS_DID","0":"COS_DID","CODE1":"aaaaaa","1":"aaaaaa","CODE2":"TestGroup","2":"TestGroup","FLAG_ACTIVE":"Y","3":"Y","LAST_UPDATE_DTTM":"2013-11-06 21:57:50","4":"2013-11-06 21:57:50"},{"COS":"COS_DID","0":"COS_DID","CODE1":"5678901234","1":"5678901234","CODE2":"TestGroup","2":"TestGroup","FLAG_ACTIVE":"Y","3":"Y","LAST_UPDATE_DTTM":"2013-11-06 21:59:14","4":"2013-11-06 21:59:14"},{"COS":"COS_DID","0":"COS_DID","CODE1":"1112223344","1":"1112223344","CODE2":"TestGroup","2":"TestGroup","FLAG_ACTIVE":"Y","3":"Y","LAST_UPDATE_DTTM":"2013-11-06 22:21:23","4":"2013-11-06 22:21:23"},{"COS":"COS_DID","0":"COS_DID","CODE1":"5555555555","1":"5555555555","CODE2":"TestGroup","2":"TestGroup","FLAG_ACTIVE":"Y","3":"Y","LAST_UPDATE_DTTM":"2013-11-06 22:43:37","4":"2013-11-06 22:43:37"},{"COS":"COS_DID","0":"COS_DID","CODE1":"2222222222","1":"2222222222","CODE2":"TestGroup","2":"TestGroup","FLAG_ACTIVE":"Y","3":"Y","LAST_UPDATE_DTTM":"2013-11-06 22:47:20","4":"2013-11-06 22:47:20"},{"COS":"COS_DID","0":"COS_DID","CODE1":"6666666666","1":"6666666666","CODE2":"TestGroup","2":"TestGroup","FLAG_ACTIVE":"Y","3":"Y","LAST_UPDATE_DTTM":"2013-11-06 23:00:44","4":"2013-11-06 23:00:44"},{"COS":"COS_DID","0":"COS_DID","CODE1":"3331231234","1":"3331231234","CODE2":"TestGroup","2":"TestGroup","FLAG_ACTIVE":"Y","3":"Y","LAST_UPDATE_DTTM":"2013-11-06 23:06:26","4":"2013-11-06 23:06:26"},{"COS":"COS_DID","0":"COS_DID","CODE1":"4321234123","1":"4321234123","CODE2":"TestGroup","2":"TestGroup","FLAG_ACTIVE":"N","3":"N","LAST_UPDATE_DTTM":"2013-11-07 14:50:33","4":"2013-11-07 14:50:33"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `zTable` is not defined is your problem, just change its scope to global and access it.

```
var zTable = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    zTable = $('#tblDIDs').dataTable({
```

Comment: You're right, that fixed it.  I was able to open the console and try 'zTable.fnReloadAjax();' and it worked.  Thank you.